# How to list standalone plugins in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse we can list either all installed plugins or features. The belonging plugins to a feature can also be listed individually. How can we filter out to only list all the standalone plugins, which don't belong to any of the features.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet that does what you need

First we get all the features

```
            IBundleGroupProvider[] providers = Platform
                .getBundleGroupProviders();
            List<Bundle> featureBundles=new LinkedList<Bundle>();

        // create a descriptive object for each BundleGroup
        LinkedList groups = new LinkedList();
        if (providers != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < providers.length; ++i) {
                IBundleGroup[] bundleGroups = providers[i]
                        .getBundleGroups();
                for (int j = 0; j < bundleGroups.length; ++j) {
                    featureBundles.addAll(Arrays.asList(bundlegroups[j].getBundles()));
                }
            }
        }
```

Then we get all the plugins

```
Bundle[] bundles = WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getBundles()
```

Now we list those bundles that do not belong to any feature

```
List<Bundle> individualBundles=new LinkedList<Bundle>();
individualBundles.addAll(Arrays.asList(bundles));
individualBundles.removeAll(featureBundles);
```